# Set asp.net textbox value using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to set the value of a asp.net textbox using javascript

My JS Code is:

```
document.getElementById('<%=txtFlag.ClientID %>').value = "Track";
```

My  textbox is:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFlag" runat="server" Visible="False"></asp:TextBox>
```

But it gives me an error `document.getElementById(...)' is null or not an object`

I dont understand what is wrong.

Please help.

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="txtFlag" runat="server" Visible="False"></asp:TextBox>

Comment: Why you took `Visible="false"`???

Comment: Because i want that value in my codebehind file. I dont want it displayed on the page

Comment: they you have to use hiddenfield instead of textbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution 1:

Make that textbox as visible=true and try,

When you make a control as visible false, that control will not be loaded in client side and as you knew javascript will be executed on client side itself.

Solution 2:

Add this javascript at the end of the page.

Comment: Buddy he dont want to display that so solution 1 will be wrong

Comment: At the time of answering he havent gave that information, as you said  hiddenfield can be used instead of textbox..

Comment: in my case textbox is visible but still value not assign

Answer (score 8):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFlag" runat="server" Visible="False"></asp:TextBox>
```

Setting `visible=false` will cause this textbox to not appear in the rendered page. Remove this, and add `display:none;`

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFlag" runat="server" style="display:none;"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 5):

Try including the `ClientIDMode` property in your textbox

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFlag" runat="server" Visible="False" 
                                     ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 4):

You are calling javascript `before complete document load`. Please write your javascript code on `document.ready` function like this

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
        document.getElementById('<%=txtFlag.ClientID %>').value = "Track";
        });

    </script>
```

And second thing is that use display none in place of visible false or use `hidden field control`

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFlag" runat="server" style="display:none;"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById('txtFlag').value='Track'
```

try this