# FormView.InsertItem(True) not inserting

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web

I am trying to have the button(BtnTimeOut) outside my formview to insert data.  the code executes without errors but does not insert into the database.  do you have any clue what im doing wrong?  Thanks

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel_Time" runat="server">


     <table style="text-align: center" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td width="10%">
                &nbsp; 
                <asp:Button ID="btnTimeIn" runat="server" Text="Begin Day"  
                   onclick="btnTimeIn_Click" CausesValidation="False"   
                   Width="90px"  ForeColor="WhiteSmoke"
                   BackColor="#43BE07" Font-Bold="True" />

            </td>
            <td width="10%">
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td width="10%">
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td width="10%">
                &nbsp; 
                 <asp:Button ID="btnTimeOut" runat="server" Text="End Day"  
            onclick="btnTimeOut_Click" CausesValidation="False" 
              Width="90px" ForeColor="WhiteSmoke"
              BackColor="#E93240" Font-Bold="True" />   
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>

    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel_FV" runat="server">

     <table style="text-align: center" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td width="10%">

                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td width="10%">
            </td>
            <td align="center">



  <asp:FormView ID="FormView_ProdEntry" runat="server" 
  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource_FV_ProdEntry"
   DefaultMode="ReadOnly" BorderStyle="None" 
   Width="100%">
                    <%--  DefaultMode="Insert"--%>
                    <InsertRowStyle BorderStyle="Solid" />
                    <%--****************************--%>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <table style="width: 100%; text-align: center" border="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                    &nbsp;
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblMouseOver" runat="server" Text="Tip:&nbsp;&nbsp;Hover Mouse Over Any Field Label for Tool Tips / Field Definitions"
                                        ToolTip="How To Work ToolTips" Font-Italic="True" ForeColor="#525252">
                                    </asp:Label>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    &nbsp;
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    &nbsp;
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_WorkDate" runat="server" Text="Work Date" ToolTip="Date of Work Performed">
                                    </asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td align="left">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtbox_WorkDate" runat="server" value='<%# DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() %>'
                                        TabIndex="1"
                                         >
                                    </asp:TextBox>
                                     <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalExt_WorkDate" runat="server"
                                        TargetControlID="txtbox_WorkDate" CssClass="CalendarStyle" >
                                        </asp:CalendarExtender>
                                    <asp:RangeValidator ID="rangeVal_WorkDate" Type="Date" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtbox_WorkDate"
                                        ValidationGroup="ValGroup_StatEntry" ErrorMessage="WorkDate -- Date Entered Must Be Valid Format and in Range of Current Date to 90 Days Earlier."
                                        MinimumValue='<%# DateTime.Now.AddDays(-90).ToShortDateString() %>'
                                         MaximumValue="<%# DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() %> "
                                        Font-Names="tahoma" Font-Size="11px" 
                                        Text="-- Date Range or Date Format Error"
                                        Display="Dynamic" />

                                    <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" 
                                    ErrorMessage="Tasks already exist for this workdate, Edit the record using OCP020." 
                                    ControlToValidate="txtbox_WorkDate"
                                    OnServerValidate="ValidateGVDateCalcTTS" 
                                     ValidationGroup="ValGroup_StatEntry" 
                                    ></asp:CustomValidator>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_WorkDateInstr" runat="server" Text="Allowable WorkDates range from Today's Date to 90 Days Earlier."
                                        ForeColor='#484641' Font-Italic="True">
</asp:Label>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    &nbsp;
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    &nbsp;
                                </td>
                            </tr>


                             <tr>
                                <td align="right">
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label31" runat="server" 
                                    Text="Total Time" 
                                    ToolTip="The total amount of time worked so far for this WorkDate"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td align="left">
                                   <%--'mah 8-10-2016 Then changemode to ReadOnly is reset after the insert processing of the record.  Because of total time needing to be read only 
        'the system cannot read the Javascript input(rather readonly is set to false or not), therefore another field was created for input with display = none.
        'this link helped to correct the problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21036744/set-asp-net-textbox-value-using-javascript --%>

                                     <asp:TextBox ID="tbTotalTimeSpent" runat="server"
                                      Text = ''
                                    ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>

                                    &nbsp; &nbsp;
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    &nbsp;
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    &nbsp;
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_Claims" runat="server" Text="Claims" ToolTip="Number of Claims worked for this WorkDate"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td align="left">
                                    <%--    5-25-2016 MAH Autocomplete is set to off as when used
               it is not populating the modified total.--%>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_Claims" runat="server" Text='' value='<%#0%>' MaxLength="4"
                                        TabIndex="4" autocomplete="off"  onkeyup="startCalcClaims()">
                                    </asp:TextBox>
                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text=" X " Width="20 px" ForeColor="#CCCCCC"></asp:Label>
                                    <%--<asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text=" X "  Width="20 px" style="display:none" ></asp:Label>--%>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_ClaimsMod" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ClaimsMod") %>'
                                        ForeColor="#CCCCCC" onkeyup="startCalcClaims()" Width="20 px" BorderWidth="0"
                                        BorderStyle="None" Enabled="True" TabIndex="-1"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text=" = " Width="20 px" ForeColor="#CCCCCC"></asp:Label>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_ClaimsTot" runat="server" Text='' value='<%#0%>' onkeyup="startCalcClaims()"
                                        ForeColor="#CCCCCC" Width="50 px" BorderStyle="None" Enabled="True" TabIndex="-1"></asp:TextBox>

                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqfldVAL_Claims" ControlToValidate="TextBox_Claims"
                                        ErrorMessage="Claims Field CANNOT BE EMPTY. Input 0 or Valid Number." ValidationGroup="ValGroup_StatEntry"
                                        Display="Dynamic" runat="server">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                    <asp:CompareValidator ID="cmprVAL_Claims" ControlToValidate="TextBox_Claims" Operator="DataTypeCheck"
                                        Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Claims Field Must Have a VALID NUMBER OR ZERO."
                                        ValidationGroup="ValGroup_StatEntry" runat="server" Type="Integer">*</asp:CompareValidator>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right">
                                    &nbsp;
                                </td>
                                <td align="left">
                                    &nbsp;
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_Comments" runat="server" Text="Comments" ToolTip="Comments of Any Sort"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td align="left" colspan="2">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="Comments_TextBox" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" TabIndex="17"
                                        Width="215"></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right">
                                    &nbsp;
                                </td>
                                <td align="left">
                                    &nbsp;
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right">
                                    &nbsp;
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label29" runat="server" Text="Total "></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td align="left">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_Totals" runat="server" value='<%#0%>' BorderStyle="None"
                                        TabIndex="-1">
                                    </asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label30" runat="server" Text="Total Modified "></asp:Label>
                                         &nbsp; &nbsp;
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_ModTotals" runat="server" value='<%#0%>' BorderStyle="None"
                                        TabIndex="-1">
                                    </asp:TextBox>
                                    &nbsp;
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right">
                                    &nbsp;
                                </td>
                                <td align="right">
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" Text="Target Goal"></asp:Label>
                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_TGoalPH" runat="server" value='<%#0%>' BorderStyle="None"
                                        TabIndex="-1">
                                    </asp:TextBox>
                                    &nbsp;
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right">
                                    &nbsp;
                                </td>

                                <td align="right">
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label32" runat="server" Text="Prod Per Hour "></asp:Label>
                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_PPH" runat="server" value='<%#0%>' BorderStyle="None" TabIndex="-1">
                                    </asp:TextBox>
                                    &nbsp;
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td align="right">
                                    &nbsp;
                                </td>
                                <td align="left">
                                    &nbsp;
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    &nbsp;
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    &nbsp;
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <table style="width: 100%; text-align: center">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                   <%-- <asp:Button ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Insert"
                                        Text="Save" OnClick="InsertButton_Click" ValidationGroup="ValGroup_StatEntry"
                                        TabIndex="18" />
                                    &nbsp;
                                    <asp:Button ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel"
                                        Text="Cancel" TabIndex="19" />--%>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    &nbsp;
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="text-align: left">
                                    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValSummary_Insert" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ValGroup_StatEntry"
                                        Font-Size="Small" HeaderText="New Record Cannot Be Saved Due To The Following:" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <%--*************************--%>
                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <table style="width: 100%; text-align: center" border="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                    &nbsp;
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblMouseOver" runat="server" Text="Tip:&nbsp;&nbsp;Hover Mouse Over Any Field Label for Tool Tips / Field Definitions"
                                        ToolTip="How To Work ToolTips" Font-Italic="True" ForeColor="#525252">
                                    </asp:Label>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    &nbsp;
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    &nbsp;
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_WorkDate" runat="server" Text="Work Date" ToolTip="Date of Work Performed">
                                    </asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td align="left">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtbox_WorkDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("WorkDate") %>' value='<%# DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() %>' ControlToValidate="txtbox_WorkDate">
                                    </asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalExt_WorkDate" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtbox_WorkDate"
                                        CssClass="CalendarStyle">
                                    </asp:CalendarExtender>

                                <asp:RangeValidator ID="rangeVal_WorkDate" Type="Date" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtbox_WorkDate"
                                        ValidationGroup="ValGroup_StatEntry" ErrorMessage="WorkDate -- Date Entered Must Be Valid Format and in Range of Current Date to 90 Days Earlier."
                                        MinimumValue='<%# DateTime.Now.AddDays(-90).ToShortDateString() %>' MaximumValue="<%# DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() %> "
                                        Font-Names="tahoma" Font-Size="11px" Text="-- Date Range or Date Format Error"
                                        Display="Dynamic" />
                                    <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" 
                                    ErrorMessage="Can Not add tasks for this date. Use Edit(ocp020) page" 
                                    ControlToValidate="txtbox_WorkDate"
                                    OnServerValidate="ValidateGVDateCalcTTS" 
                                     ValidationGroup="ValGroup_StatEntry" 
                                    ></asp:CustomValidator>

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_WorkDateInstr" runat="server" Text="Allowable WorkDates range from Today's Date to 90 Days Earlier."
                                        ForeColor='#484641' Font-Italic="True">
</asp:Label>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    &nbsp;
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    &nbsp;
                                </td>
                            </tr>


                   <tr>
                                <td align="right">
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label31a" runat="server" 
                                    Text="Total Time" 
                                    ToolTip="The total amount of time worked so far for this WorkDate"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td align="left">
                                     <asp:TextBox ID="tbTotalTimeSpent" runat="server"
                                    Text='<%# Bind("TotalTimeSpent") %>'
                                    ></asp:TextBox>

                                    &nbsp; &nbsp;
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    &nbsp;
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    &nbsp;
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right">
                                                                    </td>
                                <td align="left">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_Claims" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Claims") %>' value='<%#0%>'
                                        MaxLength="4">
                                    </asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                                <td align="left">
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ClaimsMod") %>' value='<%#0%>'></asp:Label>
                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqfldVAL_Claims" ControlToValidate="TextBox_Claims"
                                        ErrorMessage="Claims Field CANNOT BE EMPTY. Input 0 or Valid Number." ValidationGroup="ValGroup_StatEntry"
                                        Display="Dynamic" runat="server">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                    <asp:CompareValidator ID="cmprVAL_Claims" ControlToValidate="TextBox_Claims" Operator="DataTypeCheck"
                                        Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Claims Field Must Have a VALID NUMBER OR ZERO."
                                        ValidationGroup="ValGroup_StatEntry" runat="server" Type="Integer">*</asp:CompareValidator>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_Comments" runat="server" Text="Comments" ToolTip="Comments of Any Sort"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td align="left" colspan="2">
                                    >
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="Comments_TextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Comments") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <table style="width: 100%; text-align: center">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
<%--                                    <asp:Button ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Insert"
                                        Text="Save" OnClick="InsertButton_Click" ValidationGroup="ValGroup_StatEntry" UseSubmitBehavior="True" />
                                    &nbsp;
                                    <asp:Button ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel"
                                        Text="Cancel" TabIndex="19" />--%>

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    &nbsp;
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="text-align: left">
                                    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValSummary_Insert" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ValGroup_StatEntry"
                                        Font-Size="Small" HeaderText="New Record Cannot Be Saved Due To The Following:" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                </asp:FormView>

  </asp:Panel>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource_FV_ProdEntry" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MRATracker_ConnectionString %>"
        InsertCommand="usp_MRAPIT_UNI_ProdInfo_RowAdd_Cdr" InsertCommandType="StoredProcedure"
        OnInserted="SqlDataSource_FV_ProdEntry_Inserted" 
        SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"
        SelectCommand="usp_MRAPIT_UNI_ProdInfo_Mod_Cdr">
        <selectparameters>
        </selectparameters>
        <insertparameters>
           <asp:Parameter Direction="ReturnValue"               Name="RETURN_VALUE" Type="Int32" />
           <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="tbUser"             Name="UserID"       Type="String" />
           <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="FormView_ProdEntry" Name="WorkDate"     Type="datetime" />
           <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="FormView_ProdEntry" Name="Role"         Type="string" DefaultValue="Coder" />
           <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtTotalTimeSpent"  Name="TotalTimeSpent" Type="String" Size="8" />
           <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="FormView_ProdEntry" Name="Claims"       Type="Int32" />
           <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="FormView_ProdEntry" Name="Comments"     Type="string" />
        </insertparameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>


  Protected Sub btnTimeOut_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        'Handles btnTimeOut.Click
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Page.GetType, "Script", "Read_Data2('No');", True)
        'MAH 9-27-2016 Remove Save Cnc button from FV and Insert via this button
        'Insert formview data via this button
        FormView_ProdEntry.DefaultMode = FormViewMode.Insert
        FormView_ProdEntry.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Insert)
        Try

            FormView_ProdEntry.InsertItem(True)
            MsgLabel.Text = ""
            'SqlDataSource_FV_ProdEntry.Insert()
        Catch ex As HttpException

            MsgLabel.Text = "The FormView control must be in insert mode to insert a record."

        End Try

    End Sub
```

Comment: The answer is in the error message: `"The FormView control must be in insert mode to insert a record."` You have your FormView set to `DefaultMode="ReadOnly" `
And `Insert` is commented out: `<%--  DefaultMode="Insert"--%>`. Change ReadOnly to Insert and that might be what you need.

Comment: ThanksElroy however right before the insert item true, I change the formview to insert.   WHen its not in insertmode I get the error saying its not.  but when it is in Insert it does not insert the record.

Comment: ok I have found out that the insert is working however it only inserts data that comes from outside the formview. (out side txt boxex) but all fields from the formview are null.   What causes this?  how do i fix it?

Comment: After you click `btnTimeOut` and the page posts back, are the data fields in side the FormView empty/clear, or do they still contain the data that was in them before the click? If they are cleared with the click, it sounds like your data is not persisting after a postback. There is other code on the page that I can't see, so I can only speculate. Could you also add your `Page_Load` event handler too please?

Comment: If Page.IsPostBack Then
            If btnTimeOut.Enabled = "True" Then
                FormView_ProdEntry.Enabled = "True"
                MsgLabel2.Text = ""
                MsgLabel2.Visible = "false"

            Else
                Dim tb2 As TextBox = FormView_ProdEntry.FindControl("tbTotalTimeSpent")
                tb2.Text = ""
                FormView_ProdEntry.Enabled = "False"
            End If

        Else

Comment: Else

            strHumad = UCase(Mid((Request.ServerVariables("remote_user")), 7, 7))
            tbUser.Text = strHumad

            dv = CType(SqlDataSource_UserInfo.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty), DataView)

            strFLName = CType(dv.Table.Rows(0)(0), String)
            lblUser.Text = strFLName & " (" & strHumad & ")"

            Dim tb As TextBox = FormView_ProdEntry.FindControl("txtbox_WorkDate")
            tb.Focus()

            btnTimeOut.Enabled = False

Comment: If btnTimeOut.Enabled = "True" Then
                FormView_ProdEntry.Enabled = "True"
            Else
                Dim tb2 As TextBox = FormView_ProdEntry.FindControl("tbTotalTimeSpent")
                tb2.Text = ""
                FormView_ProdEntry.Enabled = "False"
            End If
        End If

Comment: for some reason it would not let me add the whole page load, so i had to do it in 3 pieces.   It would not add in the initial request either...   thanks for your help

Comment: There's no way for me to reconstruct that. Can you please Edit your original question and add the code there? Also, does the contents of the textbox fields remain after clicking or are they cleared when you click the button?